# Change the week start on Clock alarms

Tags: samsung, clock

Is there a way to change the start of the week to Monday (instead of Sunday) in the default clock program?

Note that my local is set to English (UK) so it should be the default but is not. I am running v4.2.2, if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's just/about to be fixed in Clock 4.0.1 as reported on [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/05/30/apk-download-the-clock-app-from-android-m-allows-users-to-start-their-week-on-saturday-sunday-or-monday/).

> The new APK for the clock app from the Android M Developer Preview doesn't look very different from the one you'll find in Lollipop - most of the functions (alarms, world clock, timer, and countdown) are in the same place and operate in the same way. But there's one tiny change that a small amount of users will be extremely happy to see. The Clock app can now "start" your week on Saturday, Sunday, or Monday.

[image: screenshot]

Update: As of 18 June 2015 the stock app on my MOTO E 2 was updated by the normal 'My Apps" update notification and I still have the option of what day to start the week.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't change it. When I set my phone's language to `French (France)`, the first day is still Sunday, where it should be Monday (like you).

Google may have skipped this...

Comment: What if you change the week start day in Calendar?

Comment: @dotVezz: Already at Monday... Clock still on Sunday :/